# R combine choropleth plot with plotting coordinates

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, choropleth

Lets say I have two datasets, `countries` and `cities`:

```
set.seed(42)

countries <- data.frame(country = c("DEU", "FRA", "ITA", "POL"),
                      intensity = abs(rnorm(4)))

cities <- data.frame(city = c("Berlin", "Paris", "Roma", "Warszawa"),
                    longitude = c(13.408333, 2.351667, 12.483333, 21.033333),
                    latitude = c(52.518611, 48.856667, 41.883333, 52.216667))
```

`countries` describes a country level dataset of intensities. `cities`is a dataset that contains coordinates.  So far I have used `rworldmap` to plot intensities:

```
library(rworldmap)

map <- joinCountryData2Map(countries, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "country")

mapCountryData(map, nameColumnToPlot = "intensity", mapRegion = "Europe")
```

How can I combine a choropleth map of the country level data with an overlay of points according to the cities dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can add points to the map using `points`:

```
map <- joinCountryData2Map(countries, joinCode = "ISO3", nameJoinColumn = "country")
mapCountryData(map, nameColumnToPlot = "intensity", mapRegion = "Europe")
points(cities$longitude, cities$latitude, col = "black", cex = 1.5)
```

Comment: great, thanks. I thought I already tried that, but obviously I missed something.